# Cordova (Ionic) : Splashscreen only works one time on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I have created a Splashscreen using the Cordova plugin by adding the plugin to my Ionic app as:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

When I install the app on my Android phone and run it for the first time, I see the splash screen working. But if I go out of the app by pressing backbutton and then reopen the app, this time I do not see the splash screen and it goes directly to the main screen. I think this is due to the fact that when I press the backbutton the app is not completely closed (exited). So if I go to the list of still running apps and close my app manually (from the list of running apps) then next time I open my app I see the splashscreen again.

I tried exiting the app when backbutton is pressed using:

```
function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, true);
}

function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
}
function onBackKeyDown()
{
 navigator.app.exitApp();
}
```

In my JavaScript code, but it didn't help.
What is a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Splashscreen's are used to show a default image when app is loading and we don't want the user to be frustated by a black screen when the app starts. As a result, android shows the splash screen on a `coldstart`(The app being started when it was killed). You usually don't need to show splashscreen on `hotstart`, but if you do you can use below JavaScript methods exposed by the splashscreen cordova plugin:

```
navigator.splashscreen.show();
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

Just make sure that you call these when the `platform` is `ready`. Alternatively, you can use `ngCordova` to provide you an injectable service api for this: http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/splashscreen/

Handle resume event:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
  document.addEventListener('resume', yourAsyncResumeCallback, false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried adding: `navigator.splashscreen.show();` inside `function onDeviceReady()` but still it does not work, do you know why?

Comment: In your case the device is being brought from background. So you can use the cordova event lifecycle event `resume`, which is called for that precise scenario. Refer: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/cordova/events/events.resume.html. Also please accept if your issue is solved :)

Comment: Can you please put the complete solution in the answer. I tried what you said by adding `navigator.splashscreen.show();` inside the `onResumeMyApp` function and I added this as well `document.addEventListener("resume", onResumeMyApp, false);` . But still not working.

Comment: All your cordova events should be checked only when the `deviceready` is fired. I have edited the code above for same.

Answer (score 0):

Your app's behaviour is weird. My app even after backbutton and reopen shows the splashscreen again. Here is my **config.xml** it works with splashscreen if you do not want deprecated version remove 'gap:' from below tags and rename version in `version="1.0.0"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id="testaplikacji"
        versionCode="1"
        version="1.0.0">

        <name>Your app name</name>
        <description>Desc</description>
        <author>Author</author>
        <gap:platform name="android">
        </gap:platform>
        <preference name="SplashScreen" value="splash" />
        <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
        <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" spec="1.0.0" source="pgb" />         
        <gap:splash src="splash.png" gap:platform="android" gap:qualifier="ldpi" width="500" height="500" /> 
        <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    </widget>
```

, **splash.png** https://i.stack.imgur.com/ALb1N.jpg and **index.html** of course assets (jqmobile1.4.2.css and .js and jquery1.11.3) local as mine '.\' or with http:... links

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link href=".\jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <script src=".\jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
        <script src=".\jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        function init() {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }

        function onDeviceReady() {
          //do stuff
        }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body onload="init()">

    </body>
</html>
```